# when i first ran my django project on local host 127.0.0.1:8000 it opened properly but now after adding product it shows 127.0.0.1 refused to connect

Tags: python, django, connection, localhost, web-development-server

[image: this is my screen]so this is the code and something i found weird is that my db.sqlite3  has a '?' (question mark) icon but the tutorial i am following has a white paper icon when i ran 127.0.0.1:8000  for first time it showed me my django local host  but now it says this site cant be reached. i tried changing local host in settings.py to 127.0.0.1

```
#view
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello world! ')


def new(request):
    return HttpResponse('New products ')

#urls
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('new', views.new)
]
```

Comment: can you send the full error trace

Comment: sorry i am a newbie can u pls tell me whats error trace

Comment: the error that you get on your terminal, right after you runserver

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/lapi/Desktop/pyshop/products/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
ImportError: cannot import name 'views' from '__main__' (C:/Users/lapi/Desktop/pyshop/products/urls.py)     (this is the error i get for views)

Comment: views.py file exists?

Comment: yes it does i have  files like view , urls , models etc

Comment: Please add the screenshot of the project structure in your question. According the error seems it cannot find your views.py module. Please share the project structure

Comment: i added a screenshot  and thanks for the help

Comment: Two quick questions, 1. are views.py and urls.py in the same directory? 2. Have you added product app into your INSTALLED_APPS list in settings.py?

Comment: Try importing like from .views import index, new

Comment: yes they both are in the same directory and i have added them in installed apps in settings.py used this (  'products.apps.ProductsConfig')